# Make 2 divs overlaping 2 other divs responsively

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

[image: Initial div configuration on large screen devices]
So,I don't know how to make divs overlap eachother in such a way and I'm curious to find out if it's even possible. If it is, is it also possible to make something like that responsive too, using bootstrap or some other library? If yes, wouldn't it be needed for the divs to completely change configuration so the content still makes sense? (like in the pic below)
[image: Div configuration on portable devices - if possible]
If something like that can't happen (referring to the responsiveness) is there a way to make the entire thing disappear and show something else instead?

Comment: You can absolutely position divs if you need them to 'overlap' as you say, but I don't understand why you would need that in your example. Why can't you just draw the div (black line) around a1, a2, a3 in the top picture as well. That is exactly how divs would flow anyway.
As for making things appear and disappear, that can be done with css media queries.
If you need to change the configuration on divs, this can also be done with css order and css grids

Comment: Ah, @BrettEast , great question, because i want to have the left div with a fixed backround image and content on it, while the right div has a solid color background and text over it, and i want to have images between them/on top of them both, so you can see throufgh the transparent partts of the picture the actual divs that are below like if they were hovering ontop.

Comment: In that case, you would need to use `position: absolute;` to achieve this. I would suggest using that on the background, rather than the divs with content, or the images.

Comment: Imma try implement it in the code and will let you know if it works, i didnt hink of it tbh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you somewhere to start?

You'll need to use a combination of `@media` queries and `flex`.

Look into `@media` queries here: [CSS @media Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Look into `flex` box here: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

This code might be of some help! (Resize the output window to see the results)

See here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rwdLnv2/)

```css
.panel-container {
  
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.panel {
 
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#a1 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#a2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#a3 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#b1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#b2 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#b3 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
   <div class="col">
     <div id="a1">A1</div>
     <div id="a2">A2</div>
     <div id="a3">A3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     <div id="b1">B1</div>
     <div id="b2">B2</div>
     <div id="b3">B3</div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="panel-container">
   <div id="lhs" class="panel"></div>
   <div id="rhs" class="panel"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

its possible. use CSS flexbox

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

youll want to switch the flex direction of the container element with a css media query and so on... this is a more html/css related problem than javascript

Comment: heres a quick fiddle to demo: https://jsfiddle.net/von5hcyL/8/. adjust the width of your browser to see the media query changes